# Smooth / blur WebGL Polygons

Tags: javascript, shader, webgl, mapbox-gl-js, gaussianblur

I have some code that generates two WebGL triangles, one green and one blue, and puts them on a `mapbox-gl-js` map. The four coordinates are those of four European cities. Here is the code I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add a custom style layer</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.12.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.12.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic3RlZXBhdHRpY3N0YWlycyIsImEiOiJjbDNvaGFod2EwbXluM2pwZTJiMDYzYjh5In0.J_HeH00ry0tbLmGmTy4z5w';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        zoom: 3,
        center: [7.5, 58],
        // Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v11',
        antialias: true, // create the gl context with MSAA antialiasing, so custom layers are antialiased
        projection: 'mercator'
    });
    
    // define vertices of the triangle to be rendered in the custom style layer
    const helsinki = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat({
      lng: 25.004,
      lat: 60.239
    });
    const berlin = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat({
      lng: 13.403,
      lat: 52.562
    });
    const kyiv = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat({
      lng: 30.498,
      lat: 50.541
    });
    const moscow = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat({
      lng: 37.6173,
      lat: 55.7558
    });
    
    const vertex_buffer = new Float32Array([
      helsinki.x,
      helsinki.y,
      berlin.x,
      berlin.y,
      kyiv.x,
      kyiv.y,

      kyiv.x,
      kyiv.y,
      helsinki.x,
      helsinki.y,
      moscow.x,
      moscow.y
    ])
    
    const color_buffer = new Float32Array([
      0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    ])
    
    const highlightLayer = {
        id: 'highlight',
        type: 'custom',

        // method called when the layer is added to the map
        // https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#styleimageinterface#onadd
        onAdd: function (map, gl) {
            // create GLSL source for vertex shader
            const vertexSource = `
                uniform mat4 u_matrix;
                attribute vec2 a_pos;
                attribute vec4 color;
                varying vec4 vColor;
                void main() {
                    gl_Position = u_matrix * vec4(a_pos, 0.0, 1.0);
                    vColor = color;
                }`;

            // create GLSL source for fragment shader
            const fragmentSource = `
                precision lowp float;
                varying vec4 vColor;
                void main() {
                    gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor);
                }`;

            // create a vertex shader
            const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexSource);
            gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

            // create a fragment shader
            const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentSource);
            gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

            // link the two shaders into a WebGL program
            this.program = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(this.program, vertexShader);
            gl.attachShader(this.program, fragmentShader);
            gl.linkProgram(this.program);

            this.aPos = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'a_pos');
            this.color = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'color');

            // create and initialize a WebGLBuffer to store vertex and color data
            this.vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(
                gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
                vertex_buffer,
                gl.STATIC_DRAW
            );

            this.colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.colorBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(
                gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
                color_buffer,
                gl.STATIC_DRAW
            );
        },

        // method fired on each animation frame
        // https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:render
        render: function (gl, matrix) {
            gl.useProgram(this.program);
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
                gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'u_matrix'),
                false,
                matrix
            );
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexBuffer);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.aPos);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.aPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.colorBuffer);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.color);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.color, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
            gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertex_buffer.length / 2);
        }
    };

    // add the custom style layer to the map
    map.on('load', () => {
        map.addLayer(highlightLayer, 'building');
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This generates an image that looks like this:

[image]

However, I want to blur, or smooth the polygons, so they look like this:

[image]

*(disregard the fact that the map is also blurred, I just blurred the whole image so you can understand what I want the polygons to look like)*

Is there any way I can achieve this? Maybe I can implement a Gaussian blur, or use some type of shader? I'm rather new to WebGL, so I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: your mapbox token is visible

Comment: @c.m. I know, it’s a throwaway token. i provided it so that people can easily see my example.